# div element not changing its text content

Tags: javascript, html, text, innerhtml

In a css file is some text and I want to change the text content of a `div` element dynamically (first showing the 1st text, then the 2nd etc.) and the problem is that even though i see that `console.log(message[i].text)` has the text (i.e.`"Insert the FIRST text you want."` etc.), `document.getElementById("background").innerHTML = message[i].text;` is still empty.

This is the css file:

```
const message = [
    {
        "text":"Insert the FIRST text you want."
    },
    {
        "text":"Insert the SECOND text you want."
    },
    {
        "text":"Insert the THIRD text you want."
    },
    {
        "text":"Insert the FOURTH text you want."
    },
    {
        "text":"Insert the FIFTH text you want."
    },
    {
        "text":"Insert the SIXTH text you want."
    },
  {
        "text":"Insert the SEVENTH text you want."
    },
  {
        "text":"Insert the EIGHTH text you want w this is just to test the words w ww www."
    }
]
```

This is the js function:

```
function insertText(a, b){
  (function theLoop (i) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      document.getElementById("background").innerHTML = message[i].text;
      if (i++ < b-1) {    
        theLoop(i);       
      }
      else {
        i = a;
        //theLoop(i);
      }
    }, delayValue);
  })(a, b);
}
```

And this is how Im calling it:

```
var l = message.length; 
insertText(0, l);
```

Im sure it is something easy, but I cant figure it out. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please create an executable code snippet of the problem.

Comment: Please share a working snippet that demonstrate your issue.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you didn't provide details of the question like the `HTML`, the error you are getting (if any), it is really difficult to answer the question.

Though I was able to get going with your code by adding one `HTML` element and setting the value for `delayValue` in `setTimeout()`.

Try the following:

```js
const message = [
    {
      "text":"Insert the FIRST text you want."
    },
    {
      "text":"Insert the SECOND text you want."
    },
    {
      "text":"Insert the THIRD text you want."
    },
    {
      "text":"Insert the FOURTH text you want."
    },
    {
      "text":"Insert the FIFTH text you want."
    },
    {
      "text":"Insert the SIXTH text you want."
    },
    {
      "text":"Insert the SEVENTH text you want."
    },
    {
      "text":"Insert the EIGHTH text you want w this is just to test the words w ww www."
    }
]


function insertText(a, b){
  (function theLoop (i) {
    var delayValue = 1000;
    setTimeout(function () {
      document.getElementById("background").innerHTML = message[i].text;
      if (i++ < b-1) {    
        theLoop(i);       
      }
      else {
        i = a;
        //theLoop(i);
      }
    }, delayValue);
  })(a, b);
} 
var l = message.length; 
insertText(0, l);
```

```html
<div id="background"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me even though I didnt give every detail.